# Android: IF statement not working when set by preferences

Tags: java, android, string, preferences

I am having trouble using and IF statement based on a string from my preferences.

Here is the code:

```
  preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
         String themePref = preferences.getString("theme", "null");
         Log.i("Theme", "Current theme is " + themePref );


         if (themePref == "dark"){
             setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black);
         }else{
             setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light);
         }
```

I have two options at this point; light and dark.  The code successfully sets themePref as light or dark as needed, and I've confirmed via debugging, but for some reason the if statement fails.  I have manually set a string to "dark" and it then works correctly.

Am I missing something here?  Why would a string coming from the preferences process any differently?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `themePref.equals("dark")` (or even better `"dark".equals(themePref)`) to compare strings. == tells you if the string instances are the same, but two instances can have the same value and not be the same instance.

Comment: Why is `"dark".equals(themePref)` better? It just reads awkwardly IMHO.

Comment: Because in `themePref.equals("dark")`, themePref may be null, in which case you will get a NullPointerException. The alternative version has no such problem, and will just return false if themePref is null.

Answer (score -1):

Is `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(...)` returning a `java.lang.String` instance or a subclass?  I would replace `themePref == "dark"` with `themePref.equals("dark")` instead.

Comment: -1 for: String is final -> no subclasses. Also string comparison is done via `equals()`

Comment: To be fair, he/she did mention equals().